# Как удалить значение с индексом 7 в этом очереди?

Tags: python-3.x

```
q = deque([2, 7, 'python', "django", 'django', 7, 4, 6, 'PyQt5', 6, 'Numpy', 'Pandas', 6])
q.insert(7, 'Qalaisyn')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque

q = deque([2, 7, 'python', "django", 'django', 7, 4, 6, 'PyQt5', 6, 'Numpy', 'Pandas', 6])

print(q)
deque([2, 7, 'python', 'django', 'django', 7, 4, 6, 'PyQt5', 6, 'Numpy', 'Pandas', 6])

del q[7]
print(q)
deque([2, 7, 'python', 'django', 'django', 7, 4, 'PyQt5', 6, 'Numpy', 'Pandas', 6])
```